# Alamofire returns wrong encoding

Tags: swift, encoding, alamofire

I`m using

```
Alamofire.request(.GET, "http://")
        .responseString { _, _, string, _ in
            println(string)
    }
```

to make get-request. Response contains сyrillic symbols and in responseString they looks like this (top-right):

[image: top right]

How should I fix encoding?

Comment: Is there a test url that you can give to represent this behavior? It might help those trying to answer your question.

Comment: Ok, fixed the question

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use `NSUTF8StringEncoding` with Alamofire's `responseString` method:

```
Alamofire.request(.GET, "http://my1test.ru/applejesus.php?task=getCategory&categoryNumber=1")
            .responseString(encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) { (request, response, string, error) -> Void in
                if let result = string {
                    println(result)
                }
        }
```

Result:

> picture{http://ipic.su/img/img7/fs/ProdukciyaApple.1438079721.png},title{Продукция Apple}

Answer (score 3):

Now, you have to use `responseString(encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)` instead

Comment: Or just `.responseString(encoding: .utf8)` for the short version :)