# How to convert string to unicode(UTF-8) string in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, unicode, utf-8, utf-16

How to convert string to unicode(UTF-8) string in Swift?

In Objective I could write smth like that:

```
NSString *str = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:[strToDecode cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

how to do smth similar in Swift?

Comment: Maybe you can change how you decode it when you receive it? Like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31733254/alamofire-returns-wrong-encoding , is this similar?

Comment: Thanks, but it does not fit for me.  
simply speaking I need to convert this : let string = "ÐÐ°ÑÐ¿Ð°ÑÐ¸ Ð¿ÑÐ¾Ð³ÑÐ°Ð»Ð¸ ÑÑÑÐ±Ð¾Ð" to this let result = "Карпати програли футбол" . I did it with online converters converting to Unicode(UTF-8)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**Swift 4 and 5** I have created a String extension

```
extension String {
    func utf8DecodedString()-> String {
        let data = self.data(using: .utf8)
        let message = String(data: data!, encoding: .nonLossyASCII) ?? ""
        return message
    }
    
    func utf8EncodedString()-> String {
        let messageData = self.data(using: .nonLossyASCII)
        let text = String(data: messageData!, encoding: .utf8) ?? ""
        return text
    }
}
```

Comment: youre missing a 'c' in your second function (you wrote fun utf8EncodedString())

Comment: @JoshO'Connor Thanks!!

Answer (score 14):

### Swift 4:

```
let str = String(describing: strToDecode.cString(using: String.Encoding.utf8))
```

Answer (score 11):

Use this code,

```
let str = String(UTF8String: strToDecode.cStringUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding))
```

hope its helpful

Comment: thanks, but this way does solve my problem.

I like before got incorrectly displayed not Latin symbols :-(

Comment: I have a string like this:   " @ Rock-Ð¦Ð¸ÑÐ°ÑÐ°: Deep Purple " with unicode symbols (cyrilic etc). 
When I use online converter to Unicode(UTF-8) I can convert that  to this: "@ Rock-Цитата: Deep Purple"

Question is:  How to do that in Swift?

Comment: simply speaking I need to convert this : let string = "ÐÐ°ÑÐ¿Ð°ÑÐ¸ Ð¿ÑÐ¾Ð³ÑÐ°Ð»Ð¸ ÑÑÑÐ±Ð¾Ð" to this  let result = "Карпати програли футбол"  . I did it with online converters converting to Unicode(UTF-8)

Comment: what is the online converter please mention here and from what format to UTF-8 please mention the two formats also

Comment: `let cString = qString.cString(using: String.Encoding.utf8)`