# How convert string to utf-8? (Swift, Alamofire)

Tags: swift, string, post, alamofire

Me need so that Alamofire send utf-8 parameters to my server, now he transmits English characters normally, but Russian characters as hieroglyphs. After checking the encoding I found that it is used maccyrillic characters.

let parameters: Parameters = ["username": login.text!, "password": password.text!]

```
        Alamofire.request("link ti site", method: .post, parameters: parameters).responseJSON { response in

            switch response.result {
            case .success:

                let json = JSON(response.result.value)

            case .failure( _):

                var errorString = "NULL"

                if let data = response.data {
                    if let json = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as! [String: String] {
                        errorString = json["error"]!
                    }
                }

            }

        }
```

Need your help. Thanks you.

Comment: var strUtf8:ContiguousArray<CChar> = "you string here".utf8CString

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Swift 3**

```
let newStr = String(utf8String: stringToDecode.cString(using: .utf8)!)
```

[Source StackOverFlow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37087408/5259363)