# How to show special character in UILabel iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, unicode, uilabel, nsdictionary

I am trying to implement an app where I would like to show some text in Spanish format. For example I would like to show "España" but in my label it shows "Espa√É¬±a" and also it changes the text for some of other text.

How to get rid of these. If anybody could help. Thanks.

Edit: When i am getting my response it logs that Below result

Message =                     (
                        "Espa\U221a\U00c9\U00ac\U00b1a:1.3\U221a\U00c7\U00ac\U00a2/min"
                    );

But when i extract the value according to key from Dictionary it shows

Espa√É¬±a:1.3√Ç¬¢/min

It means when i am getting the value from dictionary it cant do proper decoding.

how to resolve this. Any idea..?

Comment: "España" displays on my label. Please add your code.

Comment: it is working, please share your code

Comment: "España" directly is showing in my label. But when it comes from response it is not showing properly. Is there any way to parse HTML unicode to iOS unicode.?

Comment: @Tann Add the code where you parse response to get text

Comment: I am getting the responser as a dictionary. here is my code => 
NSString *message = [[[[response objectForKey:@"key1"]objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"key2"] objectAtIndex:0]; In this message string i am getting the value.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert string to unicode(UTF-8) string in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37087325/how-to-convert-string-to-unicodeutf-8-string-in-swift)

Answer (score 0):

First convert your response String to `NSData` using `NSUTF8StringEncoding` encoding, then again convert the same data to finalString like below.

```
NSString *string = @"España"; //Your response String goes here
NSData *data = [string dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSString *finalString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
lblTemp.text = finalString;
```

**UPDATE 1**

I think there is some error from your response, Please see below

```
NSString *string = @"Nu\\u0161a Florjan\\u010di\\u010d";
NSString *finalString = [NSString
                   stringWithCString:[string cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
                   encoding:NSNonLossyASCIIStringEncoding];
NSLog(@"finalString = %@", finalString);
```

Output of above code is,

```
finalString = Nuša Florjančič
```

**UPDATE 2**

If you want output string like **"España"**, your desired response should be **"Espa\u00F1a"**, Find below,

```
NSString *string = @"Espa\\u00F1a";
NSString *finalString = [NSString
                         stringWithCString:[string cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
                         encoding:NSNonLossyASCIIStringEncoding];
NSLog(@"%@",finalString);
```

Output is **España**

Comment: there might be some other problem with the response, it is perfect solution

Comment: i am getting this => "Espa\U221a\U00c9\U00ac\U00b1a" in my response.

Comment: give me some time, let me try it

Comment: NSString *string = @"Espa\U221a\U00c9\U00ac\U00b1a"; it gives me error - Incomplete universal character name

Comment: It should be small \u221a, small u

Comment: i know. i did that one also. But still not getting the proper string. But in my postman i am getting Proper string/value.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171233/discussion-between-ppl-and-tann).